# XAML gradient issue in UWP for some devices

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I'm using `Page` as landing screen in my app. XAML looks like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="7*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Rectangle StrokeThickness="0" Fill="#FF79D2F4" Margin="0,0,0,-10" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>

        <Rectangle StrokeThickness="0" Fill="#FF1F8CC5" Margin="0,-10,0,0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>

        <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/ViewMedia/Banners/Banner_Light_Big.jpg" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>

        <Rectangle StrokeThickness="0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#7F000000" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>

    </Grid>

    <StackPanel MaxWidth="300" Margin="20,35"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">

        <Button x:Name="LoginButton" x:Uid="LoginButton" Style="{StaticResource BrandButtonStyle}" Margin="0,5"
                Click="LoginButton_Click"/>

        <Button x:Name="RegisterButton" x:Uid="RegisterButton" Style="{StaticResource BrandButtonStyle}" Margin="0,5"
                Click="RegisterButton_Click"/>

    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

I've got 3 devices on which I'm running the app:

- Microsoft Lumia 950 XL [**M**]
- Custom build PC [**PC**]
- Lenovo ThinkPad Tablet 2 [**T**]

When running the app this page renders well on **M** and **PC** but on **T** `Gradient` and two `Button`s at the bottom are not rendered at all. I don't see them but I can press `Button`s and their tap event handlers will strike. But if I comment `Rectangle` with gradient everything is fine on all devices.

This is how the app looks on **T** when using gradient. No buttons. And gradient is also not visible.
[image: With gradient]

This is how the app looks on **T** without gradient. Buttons are in place.
[image: Without gradient]

And this is how it should look running on **PC**. Buttons and gradient are visible.
[image: This is how it should look]

I don't see any errors in output when running the app. I don't know why this happens only on specific devices. Maybe this is kind of known issue?

**UPDATE 1**

From users feedback, I can say that this bug hits only Atom-powered devices. But I'm not sure if this is 100% true for all Atom-powered devices.

**UPDATE 2**

I'd updated **T** with W10 from Insider Preview Fast Ring. The bug is in place. So this is not connected to OS builds.

**UPDATE 3**

Switching `Button`s `Style` back to normal does not solve this. So `Style` is good, it's not the cause.

Comment: Is BrandButtonStyle doing anything fancy? I'm still curious how you're getting those waves and stuff haha I kind of want to pick apart your layout. :)

Comment: @ChrisW. changing buttons Style to default one doesn't help.

Comment: Oh, dude, specify an actual start color for your first gradient stop even if there's no color. Try swapping `<GradientStop Offset="0"/>` with `<GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="0"/>` or `Transparent` or `{x:Null}` just something to provide a value of start to stop of the offset.

Comment: Are you sure you have the same Windows 10 build on both computers? Could one of them be using an insider build?

Comment: @ChrisW. default value for color is #00000000. So there is no problem with it.

Comment: @KooKiz, PC and phone are on Insider Fast builds. tablet is on regular builds. I will update tablet with insider builds later to see I this is causing tis issue.

Comment: @KooKiz, as it turns out W10 build is not caused this issue. Checked on PC on regular build and updated tablet to insider fast - issue is in place.

Comment: @khamitimur you havent provided the main code of `StaticResource BrandButtonStyle` the issue occurs on your button Style and the code you have provided are for background page. Also try changing your StackPanel HorizontalAlignment
`<StackPanel MaxWidth="300" Margin="20,35" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom"> 
<Button x:Name="LoginButton" x:Uid="LoginButton" Margin="0,5" Content="login" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    />....</StackPanel>'

Comment: @Jerin event I use default `Style` for button this issue is in place. I don't see any reason why changing `HorizontalAlignment` will help. And it didn't.

Comment: It would help because if you look at current code in designer then it would align those two buttons to left initially than align it tom center. the thing is `{StaticResource BrandButtonStyle}` isnt a predefined style but a custom style instead. I wanted to check if the issue is caused due to default theme being changed on your tablet by any chance.

Comment: @Jerin, I mean I used default `Style`. same issue with it. And why with `HorizontalAlignment` it will align `Button`s to left side and then to center?

Comment: @khamitimur here is the [your code](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=72A2505C9C6FA57C!4891&authkey=!AEQfjAupx557gH8&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng) on resized window now compare this with [Horizontal Alignment=Center](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=72A2505C9C6FA57C!4890&authkey=!ADHpaRlxzXuRXBA&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng). You will find your code to be more left aligned than center.

Comment: @Jerin, I tooked care of it in `Style`. `Button`s are alighned as `Stretch`.

Comment: If you change  `<StackPanel MaxWidth="300" Margin="20,35"                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">` to 
`<StackPanel MaxWidth="300" Margin="20,35"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top">`
 Will you still not be able to see the buttons?

Comment: @G.Y, nope. same issue with.

Comment: And if you remove everything else and just keeping the buttons with the stackpanel? same issue?? still not see buttons?? if so, can I assume that the problem is actually wider than that specific app and meaning that buttons will not show at all with lenovo thinkpad? is that a correct assumption? is that a fact?

Comment: @G.Y, as I said, If I remove `Rectangle` with gradient everuthing is alright. I can not test this on wider range of devices but for now it looks like only Atom powered devices are having this issue.

Comment: Is this possibly an issue with the placement in the LayoutRoot-Grid? You could try if it works when you move the buttons into the same Grid Cell as the Rectangle which causes the issue (into the inner Grid). I'm more thinking of how one could work around that issue - as going by your data this seems like a bug.

Comment: Is there any reason why the `StackPanel`, that contains the `Button`s, is the only component that does not belong to the same `Grid` as the other components ? And have you tried to move the mentioned `StackPanel` to the same `Grid` cell as the one of the `Rectangle` that contains the gradient ?

Comment: Just an idea, but maybe it's the behavior of rendering in WPF. There is a know issus in Win8.1 where you have to disable hardware rendering like this in code: RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode = RenderMode.SoftwareOnly; https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jgoldb/2010/06/22/software-rendering-usage-in-wpf/

Comment: @Smartis: Does UWP/WinRT use the same rendering engine as WPF? RenderOptions is WPF-only.

Answer (score 1):

<del>Try removing the `Grid.RowSpan="2"` from the `Rectangle` (or add a `RowDefinition`), you have 4 rows (4 `RowDefinition`) but with the `Rectangle` having `Grid.RowSpan=2` it adds up to 5 rows, so it might be causing you trouble.</del>

**EDIT:** My bad, `Rectangle` actually spans over rows 2 and 3 (`Grid.Row="2"`), so it's ok.

Since you're just stacking `<StackPanel>` over `<Grid>` (with nothing fancy), you could try to replace the root layout `<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">` with `<Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot">` and see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across similar issues, and went for a different and more portable approach.

I made a gradient image of height 1 (to save space), and sufficient pixels in width to give the proper gradient resolution. Added an image and stretched it. Quite a bit faster and offloads the renderling pipeline as well.

And it works just as well in Xamarin.Forms.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the rectangle has a *gradient* in it is a probably a "red herring".

Focus first on why the buttons don't appear at all. Once you solve that, it should be easy to add the gradient.

There are two likely reasons:

1. Adding the rectangle pushes the buttons down offscreen.

or 2. The renderer "choked" on the gradient, and didn't render anything else after it encountered it.

IMHO, #1 is more likely. I say that because I notice your overlaid StackLayout has `VerticalAlignment="Bottom"`. So if the layout engine has (mistakenly?) decided that the single cell in the outermost grid *is much taller than the screen*, then two things will happen: the gradient will be stretched very far vertically (so appears not to change), and the buttons will be pushed off the bottom of the screen.

#2 would be a renderer bug involving gradient (but I doubt that will be the case).

---

back to #1:

What is the actual pixel height of "Banner_Light_Big.jpg"? Consider making a smaller version for the device giving you trouble [picking a version based on device height in inches or in pixels, not sure which applies here]. If you remove the banner completely, does the problem go away?  If so, but you don't want to shrink it, you might need to override layout (measure?) method and do your own calculation.

Alternatively, change the two "Auto" heights to "NN*" or "NN" (NN = any specific number): anything *with no "Auto"s* will almost surely eliminate the problem.

If the resulting "non-Auto" layout isn't exactly what you want, at least it will give you a working starting point, from which to try slightly different variations on how to nest these elements, to get the desired spacing.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the color attribute and value for the first Gradient stop as well.
Maybe since only a single color is specified, it takes the same color and applies throught the button.

```
<Rectangle.Fill>
      <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Offset="0"/> // add color attribute here
            <GradientStop Color="#7F000000" Offset="1"/>
      </LinearGradientBrush>
</Rectangle.Fill>
```